# Looking for CIS Benchmark script for CentOS 7

Tags: centos, centos7, vulnerabilities

I am not sure this is the right place to ask this. I apologize if it is not.

I have few CentOS machines that is running 7.7 version. And I need to do a CIS benchmark for finding any vulnerabilities. I already have the PDF document for all the vulnerabilities but not the script itself.

Can someone help me with this? And I don't want to remediate anything as of now, I only need to scan the system for any vulnerabilities.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Since there is no further description what kind of script you are looking for, in example Ansible, Bash, Python, etc. you may have a look into the following

**Ansible**

- [Configure a RHEL/CentOS 7 machine to be CIS compliant](https://github.com/ansible-lockdown/RHEL7-CIS)
- [CIS Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7 Benchmark for Level 2 - Server](https://github.com/RedHatOfficial/ansible-role-rhel7-cis)
- [Idempotent CIS Benchmarks for RHEL/CentOS Linux V2](https://galaxy.ansible.com/HarryHarcourt/Ansible-RHEL7-CIS-Benchmarks)
- [CIS Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7 Benchmark for Level 2 - Server](https://galaxy.ansible.com/RedHatOfficial/rhel7_cis)
- [RHEL 7 - CIS Benchmark Hardening Script](https://github.com/radsec/RHEL7-CIS)

**Bash**

- [CIS benchmark for RHE7](https://access.redhat.com/discussions/3169281)

I am not aware of other Bash scripts, but it is quite simple to implement everything from the PDF into a script or just by following the Ansible roles.

**Further Readings**

- [Implementing security benchmarks with Red Hat Ansible Automation Platform](https://www.redhat.com/en/blog/implementing-security-benchmarks-red-hat-ansible-automation-platform)

Comment: Thanks a lot for these resources :)